# Windows OEM Licencing - Are "No OS" Computers OK?

Tags: windows, oem, licensing

I'm planning to buy a new PC, and I'm considering a PC with no shipped OS because I'm undecided if I'll install Windows 7 or Linux - I'm not paying the Microsoft Tax unless I have to.

As far as I know, OEM Windows licenses need to be purchased with system components like RAM. Would a complete assembled system with no OS installed satisfy this requirement, or would I need to actually purchase a standalone component to qualify?

Comment: "I'm not paying the Microsoft Tax unless I can avoid it." This implies that you'll pay it only in the case where you have a means of not paying it, which leads me to suspect you've got the sense of your test reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither, actually. The provision that an OEM license must be sold merely with "a system component" went out with XP, no doubt because of how extensively it was abused; you'd commonly find OEM copies of XP being sold with a $5 serial mouse from a junk box, purely in order to satisfy the requirement that it be sold with "a system component". Ever since then, Windows OEM licenses have explicitly stipulated that they be sold only with a fully assembled machine.

There exists one exception, but only if you're installing Windows 8; for that version of the Windows OS, there exists [a personal-use license](http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/personal-use-license.aspx#fbid=UiPQLicqJfB) which permits the purchase and installation of an OEM copy on a system you build for your own use. Per that page, though, the same provision does not exist for Windows 7; in that case, you're required to purchase a retail boxed copy, and may not install an OEM-licensed copy on a personal-use machine for any reason.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, though it would help clarify things if you could give an explicit Yes/No answer to my question as well as the great explanation." ... Windows OEM licenses have explicitly stipulated that they be sold only with a fully assembled machine." - can you clarify "sold with"? Does that mean I can purchase a Windows license as a separate line-item or does it mean that it can only be sold pre-installed on a PC, and if the latter is the case, why are retailers still selling OEM Windows 7 licenses?

Comment: @CraigWatson The answer to your question, in short, is: if you're building a PC for your personal use, you must purchase a boxed retail copy of Windows 7 to install on it; there is no circumstance in which you can fulfill the OEM license. "Sold with", in the case of Windows 7, means "preinstalled via the OEM Preinstallation Kit". Windows 8 offers the personal-use exception for OEM licenses; Windows 7 does not. Retailers selling OEM Windows 7 copies with personal-use machines are doing so outside the terms of the license.